# Can one install the full Linux system to Orange Pi or Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

There were so called official images such as Raspberry OS or Orange OS.

However, is it possible to create a USB flash drive installation image (Ubuntu for desktops or Fedora Workstation), and install a full Linux system to Orange Pi or Raspberry Pi like that of a laptop?

Comment: Does the "*Orange Pi or Raspberry pi* [sic]" have a graphical display and input devices as well as the storage capacity "*like that of a laptop*"? Also "*full Linux system*" is ambiguous. Are you trying to install every possible driver and available package that you probably don't need or will use?

Comment: @sawdust I'm not surre but Orange Pi 5 has an ARM CPU and a GPU, even a NPU. The SD card slot can handle 1TB where I recall to run a Linux from a SD card on a computer, The Raspberry Pi 5 even has a PCIE line, that can be used to connect an external GPU.

Comment: I mentioned most of that in my answer to you.

Answer (score 2):

See:   [Linux on RP4](https://emteria.com/blog/raspberry-pi-4-os#:%7E:text=The%20Raspberry%20Pi%204%20can,4%20OSes%20were%20created%20equal.)

> The Raspberry Pi 4 can run several different distributions of embedded
> Linux and embedded Android OSes. Even a watered-down version of
> Windows can run on the Raspberry Pi 4. But not all Raspberry Pi 4 OSes
> were created equal.
>
> Essentially, a Raspberry Pi 4 OS must be stable, lightweight, and be
> compatible with the Raspberry Pi's hardware.

See the 2024 Raspberry Pi Handbook  p 11 for Raspberry Pi 5:

> Raspberry Pi 5 can run a variety of operating systems .... you have a
> lot of Linux and other ARM based operating systems to choose from.

Remember RP Pi 5 has an ARM CPU (BCM2712 SoC chip with ARM Cortex-A76 CPU ).

I changed from Pi 4 to now Pi 5 just recently and it is nice and very fast machine. Use the Pi 5 if you can.

It has 8 GB of memory and connections for SSD or HDD to make it work like a laptop.

I have a screen, keyboard and mouse for my RP.

One thing native RP Pi5 does much better than Pi 4 is automatic updates. Google Chrome browser is now built in.  So Raspian OS has very much grown up as an alternative to Linux you might use.

Comment: I kind of know that the official images on Raspberry Pi website can be ran on Raspberry Pi 5, but I wonder if a native image such as https://alt.fedoraproject.org/alt/ can be ran on Raspberry Pi out of box? How about the rockchip RK3588s on the Orange Pi? I want to find an OS that I can stick with and available to wild range of ARM based SBCs. This way I won't be worry about the upgrade from Pi 4 to Pi 5 even Pi 6 Orange 8 etc. and all my code would be compatible with that OS.

Comment: The RP Pi 4 is not an ARM processor so I am not sure you can do an straight upgrade, but you should be able to transfer your code and run it in the ARM based Linux.

Comment: `The RP Pi 4 is not an ARM processor` - so what is it?

Comment: https://s-o-c.org/is-raspberry-pi-4-arm-or-arm64/#:~:text=The%20Raspberry%20Pi%204%20is,arm64%20device%20rather%20than%20ARM.   ...  The PI 4 is different than an ARM machine (at leaset that is how I read the article     The Raspberry Pi 4 is based on the ARM Cortex-A72 processor which uses the ARMv8-A 64-bit instruction set architecture.

Comment: It is ARMv8-A 64-bit  which appears to be  a predecessor to a true ARM

Comment: The only point above was that (I think) one would move coding projects to the new environment.  That was really what what I was commenting on.

Comment: The RP Pi 4 has an BCM2711 Cortex-A72 (ARM v8) while the RP Pi 5 has a BCM2712 Cortex A76. Both are 64-bit ARM processors.

Comment: @John - Well your answer is factually incorrect. Both devices have 64-bit ARM processors.

Comment: I took my specification from the Raspberry 5 book.  I changed the answer to be exact Hopefully that will satisfy you.  The answer is to inform people that an RP Pi5 can work like a regular computer with  SSD and good video

Comment: I trust my corrections satisfy people.

Comment: @John - Anyone who did any research before asking this type of question would know that a RPi 4 and RPi 5 can run both Windows on ARM and appropriate versions of ARM distributions of Linux. The answer is correct now since you removed your original comment that wasn’t correct